# number of executed bytes when debugging a PE

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, x86

I am currently writing a small debugger in assembly on windows plateform.

I open the debuggee process as follow:

```
invoke    CreateProcess, addr buffer, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS+DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, addr startinfo, addr pi
```

It works well, i can get the EIP by looking on the context of the debuggee and so i can get the 1st byte of the instruction that will be executed.

However, I need to get the number of bytes that have been executed in the previous instruction.

Instructions are not size independant. Sometimes an instruction is just 1 byte, and some other time 6 bytes or more.

I tried to substract the previous EIP with the current EIP in order to get the number of bytes that have been executed. But it doesn't work if there is a jmp or a call because the address space is not the same anymore.

I planned to get a map of all opcode and make some cmp, but it seems to be a huge work to do.

If you have some idea in order to get the number of byte of the previous instruction that has been executed (maybe looking into a cache or something like that), please let me know.

Best regards

Comment: hack-ish possibility: you can detect `jmp/jcc/loop/call/ret/int/syscall/not-sure-what-else-does-jump` ahead of execution and have large tables for those, and use your hack of `newIP-oldIP` for everything else. This will be still tricky as you can add many various (even useless in particular context) prefixes even ahead of those jumpy instructions. Also not sure what you get if your debugging allows to single-step over single transaction of instructions like `rep movsb`, do you get then `0` size? ... proper solution: it's hard, I would rather use some library like keystone or NASM disassembler.

Comment: (I'm not aware of any way how to fetch this info directly from CPU at runtime in dynamic way, i.e. getting correct answer even for future instructions/etc... would be nice, but your hack-ish way is actually most robust for that, it can be thrown out only by newly introduced jump instructions)

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Keep it simple: single step and decode only the branch instructions and use `EIP - last EIP` unless the last instruction was a branch (in that case use the decoding to find the length).
If an unknown instruction is found, back off and don't provide its size.

---

It's impossible to decode an x86 instruction stream backward because x86 encoding is not symmetric (w.r.t. address growth), to see this consider `mov eax, 90909090h` or similar.

So you need to disassemble each instruction as you single step through the program (a debugger needs this anyway) and record its size.
The control transfer instructions are significantly less than the total number of instructions, so you could decode just that and use the `EIP - EIP'` (where `EIP'` is the  EIP of the last instruction) trick otherwise.

Intel processors support Last Branch Recording but it requires OS support and you'd need to post-process the data anyway, it's seem too burdensome.
A similar argument can be made for the Intel Processor Trace technology.

I can't think of any event for the performance counters (granted that you can use them) that would result in the the number of bytes of an instruction.
Actually in the backend, the concept of "instruction" has been reduced to a sequence of uOPs (probably with a bit to say that an opcode is the last one in an instruction) and the front-end is mostly decoupled from the architectural value of `eip` (working almost always with a speculative value of `eip`) so it may be several instructions ahead of the backend.
I believe each uOP probably have a field to record how to update `eip` at retirement but not the size of an instruction in bytes.
Similarly in the front-end only in the pre-decode stage an instruction length in bytes is recorded, after that I think it's discarded (I can't think of any use of it).

Instructions in the L1 instruction cache are not yet decoded, so even if there was a way to inspect their content *and metadata* there would be nothing there.

The usual way this is done is by making a trace: single step thorough the program, disassemble the instruction at `eip` (see below), record its size, resume the program, repeat until a stop condition.
This gives you a list of addresses and instruction sizes.
If you find an instruction you can't decode you either not record the size for it or try to estimate it with some heuristic (its length must be less than 16B and you could in theory integrate the data with the count from a PMC like `BR_INST_RETIRED.ALL_BRANCHES`).

[It's possible to detect the size of an instruction at runtime but that's totally not feasible in this context](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Domas-Breaking-The-x86-Instruction-Set-wp.pdf).